# Route variables without preceding slash in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml, symfony-2.3

I am using Symfony 2.3.

Currently I'm adapting my routing.yml to be using a variable that I define in parameters.yml. I choose a parameter for each client/project, however there is a time that I need it to be empty.

By default (I guess), SF do require a preceding slash before the variable.

This is my current working **routing.yml**:

```
index:
    path:      /{_namespace}/
    defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:User:index
      _namespace: %namespace%
    methods:  [GET]

welcome:
    path:      /{_namespace}/welcome
    defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:User:welcome
      _namespace: %namespace%
    methods:  [GET]
```

And my **parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    # [....]
    namespace: 'project1'
```

And this let me produce URLs like:

http://www.domain.com/project1/

http://www.domain.com/project1/welcome

However, like I've said previously, I do need to have routes like:

http://www.domain.com/

http://www.domain.com/welcome

For that, I've tried the following (notice the exclusion of the preceding slash):

**routing.yml:**

```
index:
    path:      {_namespace}/
    defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:User:index
      _namespace: %namespace%
    methods:  [GET]

welcome:
    path:      {_namespace}/welcome
    defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:User:welcome
      _namespace: %namespace%
    methods:  [GET]
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
parameters:
    # [....]
    namespace: ''
```

And an exception occurs:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                 
Cannot import resource "/home/cupaofarmacia/src/Ongagement/AppBundle/Resour  
ces/config/routing.yml" from "/home/project/app/config/routing.yml".   
(Malformed inline YAML string ({_namespace}/) at line 51 (near "path:        
{_namespace}/").)                                                            

[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]                            
Malformed inline YAML string ({_namespace}/) at line 51 (near "path:      {  
_namespace}/").
```

I really need to be able to pass an empty variable at the start of the route.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can generate the routes you mentioned if you keep the slash and provide defaults for `_namespace`.

Comment: However my default needs to be empty, that would generate an url like "//welcome".

Comment: What do you mean with needs to be empty? can't you just provide a placeholder for it? if you do then the preceding slash will be ignored and it will be "/welcome".

Comment: Well the placeholder is exactly the {_namespace}, however passing an empty parameter to it will lead to a wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is something like conditional routes in Symfony2. What I suggest is that you create a specific route for the case the namespace will be empty.

```
#_namespace not empty
welcome:
    path:      /{_namespace}/welcome
    defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:User:welcome
      _namespace: %namespace%
    methods:  [GET]

#namespace empty
welcome2:
    path:      /welcome
    defaults:
      _controller: AppBundle:User:welcome
    methods:  [GET]
```

Noticed that the placeholder and its default value are not there now.

In the controller or in the view you just check the value of the parameter _namespace and call one of the routes.

```
//If you use the route in the controller, with generateUrl fonction for example

$namespace= $this->container->getParameter('_namespace');
if($namespace!= '') { //use welcome }
else { //use welcome2 }
```

Do the twig corresponding if you use the route in the view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Kaem, I appreciate your answer, however having duplicated routes is not really in my plans. I guess I'm gonna stick with an general purpose keyword for the namespace.

Thanks a lot!